# How to group similar names in index

Tags: indexing

I am using the `makeidx` indexing package.

I am trying to make an index and I want to group similar names, like say {continious function, differential function, etc} together, i.e. so that it displays it like

```
functions, continious, ... p.10
           differential, . p.20
```

etc.

I tried `\index{&functions&, continious}` but that does not work. Sorry I could not find anything on the web. Cheers.

Comment: Are you after `\index{functions!continuous}` and `\index{functions!differential}`?

Comment: take a look at the documentation for `makeindex:, the program that does the sorting.  that's where the input is described.  `texdoc makeindex` if you're working on a tex live installation.

Comment: cheers mate. the ! was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll answer if we can't find a duplicate. Did you find one? I've been unsuccessful in searching so far.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well there are lots of q/a mentioning it in passing but nothing directly addressing this topic (that I have found so far).

Comment: @barbarabeeton `texdoc` works also for miktex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groups like these are known as subentries in `makeindex` terminology. You can create them using the `!` character in your index command to create the nesting structure; for example:

```
\index{functions!continuous} 
\index{functions!differential}
```

Sub-subentries are also allowed, by using two exclamation points:

```
\index{equations!differential!linear}
```

however, deeper nesting is not supported by LaTeX and `makeindex`.

The [`makeindex` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/makeindex) describes the usage of these and other special characters for handling index entries in detail.